# What is data-post, data-action in magento 2? Can anyone explain wishlist functionality?

Tags: magento2, jquery, widgets

**Can anyone explain below code? How did it work?**

Is there any alternate way to do?

```
 <a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>Add to Wishlist</span></a>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you can see in widget
`lib/web/mage/dataPost.js`

```
$.each(this.options.postTrigger, function (index, value) {
    events['click ' + value] = '_postDataAction';
});
```

On click to elements which satisfy the selectors `['a[data-post]', 'button[data-post]', 'span[data-post]']` will be created and submitted form with params, specified in `data-post` attribute value.

Additionally, you can specify confirmation message

```
if (params.data.confirmation) {
    uiConfirm({
        content: params.data.confirmationMessage,
        actions: {
            /** @inheritdoc */
            confirm: function () {
                $form.appendTo('body').hide().submit();
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    $form.appendTo('body').hide().submit();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Max as usual krosava!!

Comment: @zhartaunik feel free to upvote my answers :D

Comment: I have button with this kind of data-post and I want to disbale that button once submit event fired. Example,  there is custom addtocart button, and after clicking once that button, it will be disabled and page will be redirected to my cart with that item. I have done all functionality. Just I need to prevent multiple time page submit with this data-post variable containging button.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the MagentoInstallationDirectory/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Helper/Data.php
You will see the getAddParams function which describes how product is added to the wishlist.

Comment: what is data-post and data-action? How it works?